# Opening web browser activates "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win" hotkey (Windows 10 PC)

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

I have an issue that I know is related to hot keys, but have no idea why it's happening. Here is a brief summary:

The issue started last week when suddenly whenever I opened Microsoft Edge (which I only used for viewing PDF files) my keyboard would lock up and I would have to reboot.

After some searching, I found a way to force uninstall the latest version of Edge, which solved the problem. However, a couple days ago, the same issue started happening when I opened Chrome (my primary browser). After a lot of trial and error, I was able to determine that opening Chrome essentially activated the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd> hotkey and becomes stuck on that (i.e. as if that combination is being permanently held down). So pressing "x" opens Excel, "o" opens Outlook, "w" opens Word, etc.

I would prefer not to reformat as this is my work computer and we don't have an IT person to help set everything back up. Currently I am getting by with an older version of Edge, but I'd really like to be able to use Chrome again. I have been unsuccessful in finding any mention of this issue online, which is also very confounding to me. Any help/insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your answer but I can give you a clue and a workaround.

The new edge and chrome use the same source code (chromium).  You are probably looking at a "chromium" problem and not a chrome or edge problem persay.  When you reverted Edge.. I bet it went back to using the NON CHROMIUM code. I would guess that Opera would have the same problem since it too runs chromium.

Soo.. a stupid fix ***might be*** to remap those keys **to do something harmless**.  This can be accomplished by a simple registry edit.

Run the following command from an elevated command prompt or edit the registry directly if you are up for that sort of thing.
`reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32`  If you want to be SUPER careful, you could always open that key in the registry and back it up but I myself wouldn't bother.

Note.. there is nothing special in picking `rundll32`.  If that exe is run without anything to do, it simply exits.  You could use ANY non console exe that exhibits this behavior.

I found this trick a while back [in a reddit post.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/brk0d8/ctrlaltshiftwin_opens_the_new_office_app/).  Also, I wouldn't be surprised if this specific thing was somehow related the the new round of browser wars.